# Creating carousel using php and fetching data from sql

Tags: php, html, mysqli, carousel

I am trying to create a page with carousel using php fetching `image` and `title` from sql. I created a carousel using html and css, but im not really sure how to transfer it using php.

My original carousel:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
          <img src="images/aa1.jpg">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4><b>Title</h4></b>
            <p><a class="label label-primary" href="news1.php" target="_blank" style="float: right;">Read More</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

         <div class="item">
          <img src="images/aa2.jpg">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
           <h4><b>Title</h4></b>
            <p><a class="label label-primary" href="news2.php" target="_blank" style="float: right;">Read More</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/aa3.jpg">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4><b>Title</h4></b>
            <p><a class="label label-primary" href="news3.php" target="_blank" style="float: right;">Read More</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/aa4.jpg">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4><b>Title</h4></b>
            <p><a class="label label-primary" href="news4.php" target="_blank" style="float: right;">Read More</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/aa5.jpg">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4><b>Title</h4></b>
          <p><a class="label label-primary" href="news5.php" target="_blank" style="float: right;">Read More</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    <ul class="list-group col-sm-4">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="list-group-item active"><h5>Tilte Tilte Tilte</h5></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="list-group-item"><h5>Tilte Tilte Tilte</h5></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="list-group-item"><h5>Tilte Tilte Tilte</h5></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class="list-group-item"><h5>Tilte Tilte Tilte</h5></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4" class="list-group-item"><h5>Tilte Tilte Tilte</h5></li>
    </ul>
      <!-- Controls -->
      <div class="carousel-controls">
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Now I created a database named `test` with a table named `carousel` looks like:

```
----------------------------------------------
| title | image        | link                |
----------------------------------------------
| demo  | demo.png     |images/demo.png      |
----------------------------------------------
```

I tried calling it but nothing works. I'm new to php.

My Code:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<div class=\"container\">";
        echo "<div id=\"myCarousel\"class=\"carousel slide\"data-ride=\"carousel\">";
      echo "<div class=\"carousel-inner\">";
      echo "<div class=\"item active\">";
           echo "<img alt=\"News\" src=\"images/{$row["image"]}\">";
           echo "<p>{$row["title"]}</p>";      
           echo "<ul class=\"list-group col-sm-4\"href=\"{$row["link"]}\"echo "<b><h4>{$row["title"]}">;
    <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a> <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a> </div>
       echo "</div>"
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: you need to generate your slides inside a foreach loop...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add while loop in your HTML file, try using this.

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="slidesContainer">
       <div class="slide">
         <?php
            error_reporting(E_ALL);

            $query = "SELECT id, path, name FROM images";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            echo "<img src=\"$row[path]\" title=\"$row[name]\" alt=\"\" />";
                                            }
            ?>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```